# Align & Sum Grids in Python

Tags: qgis, python, raster, resampling

I have two grids.

One, call it **A**, is 4320x2160 cells and spans the whole globe.

The other, call it **B** is 8640x3432 and spans the circumference of the globe, but is clipped toward mid-latitudes.

Both files are in ArcGrid ASCII format. The clipped file has a header of:

```
ncols         8640
nrows         3432
xllcorner     -180
yllcorner     -58
cellsize      0.0416666666667
```

Looking at the grids in QGis, I see that the **B** contains four cells for every cell of **A**.

I would like to sum each group of four cells in **B** to create a new grid that overlays directly with **A** and has a one-to-one correspondence of cells.

Is there a way to do this in Linux using either Python or command line only tools?

Comment: Do A and B already line up, or is the 4-to-1 ratio only relating to the cell size?

Comment: @Erica, **A** & **B** already line up on every other cell, giving the 4-to-1 ratio. Thank you for clarifying.